# What's the difference between array.map and rdd.map in Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I found that the map function for `RDD` generates map task, and map function of array doesn't generate any new task, so is the reduce function.

What's the difference between them, and is it encouraged to use map/reduce function instead of for/foreach anywhere anytime?

Comment: The `map` function doesn't literally mean to create a Map task.

Comment: Sparks `map` is designed to look like Scala collections `map` to make it intuitive. The usage will be pretty similar but it does a lot more under the hood than than the collections `map`.

Answer (score 2):

> I find map function for rdd generates map task, and map function of
>   array doesn't generate any new task

This is a bit of an apples to oranges comparison.

An `RDD` is an abstraction of a distributed dataset. When you're operating on one, the transformation creates a lazy evaulated `MapPartitionsRDD`, which is itself another `RDD`.

When you're working on an `Array[T]`, everything is local and in-memory, the transformation can be from an `Array[T]` an `Array[U]` or anything of that such, and it is evaluated strictly.

An `RDD` is divided into partitions, which themself can be viewed as smaller collections, each run in a distributed fashion, while an `Array[T]` has none of these properties, unless the underlying type `T` is itself an `Array[U]`.

> is it encouraged to use map/reduce function instead of for/foreach
>   anywhere anytime?

Again, it's hard to answer such a question. Map-Reduce is a general programming model used for distributed parallel computations, while `for` and `foreach` are programming constructs used for a very specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Spark scheduler (running in driver process) do not schedule any tasks for arrays or any other data structure other than `RDD` and `DStreams`.

It recognizes all operations(either transformations or actions) on `RDD/DStreams` and schedule jobs for them, which are divided into stages and further into tasks.

```
scheduler-->(knows RDD & schedules)-->Jobs-->(run in)-->Stages-->(evaluated in)-->Tasks

scheduler-->(does not know array)-->ignore
```

When you say map/reduce I consider it as [map](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@map[U](f:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$3:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) and [reduce](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream@reduce(reduceFunc:(T,T)=%3ET):org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[T]) and foreach as [foreach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@foreach(f:T=%3EUnit):Unit). All are for different purposes as described in links. Make sure what you exactly want to know here.